# What kind of permutation/combination is this?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I have 2 letters to choose from, and 3 positions I can place them in, where order matters. Lets say letters $A$ and $B$:

The possibilities, from an intuitive sense are:

$$AAA, BAA, BBA, BAB, ABB, BBB, AAB$$
and so on and so forth.

I am looking for a general formula that would give me the total number of possibilities. Would this be a permutation or a combination, or a bit of both?

Comment: How do you mean, "and so on and so forth"? Is anything other than ABA missing?

Comment: No lol. By and so on and so forth I meant ABA :P

Comment: @JMoravitz: That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @joriki fair enough.  The comment box was easier to reach and I didn't feel like formatting an answer.

Comment: so I gather the multiplication principle is something even more fundamental than the idea of a "permutation" or "combination"... very interesting

Comment: @JMoravitz: I understand, I often feel like that; it's just that this tends to result in permanently unanswered questions because often no one bothers to write an answer when the question has already been answered in a comment.

Comment: @user32882 yes.  It is from the multiplication principle that you can define and derive formulae for permutations and combinations as well as for even more complicated scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first position, pick which letter it is (either $A$ or $B$: two choices for this step).  For the second position, pick what letter it is (either $A$ or $B$: two choices for this step).  Similar for third position.  Apply [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

If you had $k$ letters to choose from and $n$ positions, this would be $k^n$.  In your specific case, $2^3=8$.  This is neither permutation nor is it combination, it is simpler than that.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Other_uses_of_the_term_permutation), some people call this "permutation with repetition". The more usual term would be "word of length $n$ over an alphabet of $k$ letters".

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  You just need to choose the locations for the A's, then the locations for the B's are known. Each of $3$ locations has $2$ choices, so ...